# what is different between compiled frame and interpreted frame?

Tags: java, jvm, biased-locking

Recently I was reading [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/biasedlocking-oopsla2006-wp-149958.pdf), and confused with "*interrupt frame*" and "*compiled frame*", what's the different? Further more, how did they generated in JVM?

Comment: "interpreted" != "interrupt", which do you mean?

Comment: And what are your thoughts? You are dumping a link to a scientific paper ... your question would probably receive much better feedback if you started with **your** ideas - so that people can confirm/enhance/... based on that. Instead of "here paper - now explain to me"

Comment: In a quick nutshell: modern JVMs can either run bytecode in "interpreted" mode (read each opcode and execute it) or in "compiled" mode (where they translate the bytecode directly to the computer's native code). This is done by the JIT, if you want to search a bit on that. A typical Java program will have some of the code be interpreted while other parts of the code has gone through the JIT, and is compiled. That's the distinction they're getting at.

Comment: this is a typo...so sorry.@T.J.Crowder

Comment: i have no much concept of just in time compile and JVM runtime mechanism.but "start with my idea" is a good suggestion to me, thanks.@GhostCat. keyword 'JIT' helps a lot,thank you so much@yshavit.